# Can an element, such as <html>'s, style be changed through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that you can select a particular id'd element and change it's style with JavaScript using GetElementById, and I know there's a way to do this with classes as well.

But is there a way to change styles associated with the html tag, the body tag, or the p tag? In other words, can you change an element's CSS using JavaScript, and if so, how? This is in contrast to changing an element by selecting it by id or class.

In particular, I'm looking to see the following accomplished through JavaScript after the page loads.

```
<style>
  html {
    height: 100%; // Just looking to add this height attribute
  }
</style>
```

Thanks for your help. I am struggling to find the solution to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use getElementsByTagName:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.height = '100%';
```

Or, you can use querySelector as well:

```
document.querySelector('html').style.height = '100%';
```

For repeating tags such as `p tags`, you can use querySelectorAll and iterate over them:

```
var ps = document.querySelectorAll('p');
for(var i=0;i<ps.length;i++){
  ps.style.height = '100%';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set and get html properties with js using attr

```
$(this).attr('height');
```

If that is what you are looking for?

Comment: The OP is about to vanilla javascript....

Comment: Ah ok, I need to read the questions twice